# sp_send_dbmail Error In Microsoft SQL Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I’m trying to send an email from a scheduled SQL Agent job using sp_send_dbmail and receive the following error:

Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 504
Query execution failed: Msg 15404, Level 16, State 19, Server MyServer, Line 1
Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'MyDomain\sqlagent', error code 0x5.

Here is the code from the job step:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(400)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT COUNT(staff_id) FROM Staff'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients = 'me@myemail.com',
@subject = 'Email Alert',
@body = 'Test',
@query = @SQL,
@execute_query_database = 'MyDB'
```

SQL Agent is running under a domain account [MyDomain\sqlagent].  I granted this user db_owner permission in the MyDB database in addition to adding it as a member of the DatabaseMailUserRole in msdb.  Still no luck.  If I remove the @query and @execute_query_database parameters it will send a ‘test’ email.  However, I need to attach the results from the query.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into some strange errors with AD in the past. I would recommend checking that the account you are running this under has it's attributes readable within AD. The quickest way to do that would be to run

```
exec xp_logininfo 'MyDomain\sqlagent'
```

and seeing if you get the same error. If you do, check the security properties of the domain account [right click the user in Active Directory > Properties > Security tab] and set Read permissions for Authenticated Users.

Comment: Nic, thanks for the information.  I ran the query you recommended and received same message I was getting.  I followed your advice for setting the AD permissions [which it did not have] and everything worked like a charm after that.  The SQL Agent job runs and the email is sent successfully.

Comment: Glad that worked out for you. I've run into that issue quite a few times recently.

Comment: This also resolved the issue for me where other answers did not (even in other SO questions that were similar).

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

'SELECT  columnname from YourDatabase.SchemaName.tablename'

I found this answer here.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7869b033-80f1-4594-a77e-fb6dce582fb4/error-msg-when-sending-email-using-spsenddbmail?forum=transactsql