# Send by mail a query result with a job in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, jobs

I'm trying to send an email by a SQL Server job with the result of a query.

The query works perfectly and I face an issue when I pass a TABLE in the `@query` parameter of `sp_send_dbmail`

Here is my code :

```
DECLARE @res TABLE 
(
  SiteCode [nvarchar](50), 
  DateLastODV [datetime]
);

INSERT INTO @res
SELECT
      SiteCode
      ,MAX(DateODV) AS DateLastODV
  FROM Configuration.ODVCompteur
  where year(DateODV) = 2015
  group by SiteCode
  order by DateLastODV desc

EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'Foo',
      @recipients = 'foo@foooo.com', 
      @subject = 'Foooooooo',
      @query = @res,      
      @Attach_Query_result_as_file = 0
```

I got this error (in french but can easily be translate if needed) :

> Line 0: Procedure: sp_send_dbmail, Msg 206, Level 16, State 2: Conflit
>   de types d'opérandes : table est incompatible avec nvarchar(max)

Comment: Are you passing `Table Variable` as parameter for `@query`?

Comment: According to MSDN, `[ @query= ] 'query'
Is a query to execute. The results of the query can be attached as a file, or included in the body of the e-mail message. The query is of type nvarchar(max), and can contain any valid Transact-SQL statements. Note that the query is executed in a separate session, so local variables in the script calling sp_send_dbmail are not available to the query.`

Comment: I want to set the result of the query in the parameter 'query' and in this example I pass the variable 'res' to 'query'

Comment: Try something like this, `@query = 'SELECT
      SiteCode
      ,MAX(DateODV) AS DateLastODV
  FROM Configuration.ODVCompteur
  where year(DateODV) = 2015
  group by SiteCode
  order by DateLastODV desc'`

Comment: I already tried this but got an error like that : `Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters [SQLSTATE 42000] (erreur 22050).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem using this code :

```
DECLARE @count TABLE(SiteCode [nvarchar](50), DateLastODV [datetime])

DECLARE @Separateur varchar(1)
DECLARE @bodyHtml NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @mailSubject NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @STMT VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @RtnCode INT

SET @Separateur=';'

INSERT INTO @count
SELECT
      SiteCode
      ,MAX(DateODV) AS DateLastODV
  FROM Configuration.ODVCompteur
  where year(DateODV) = 2015
  group by SiteCode
  order by DateLastODV DESC

BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TEMPTABLE') IS NOT NULL
    drop table ##TEMPTABLE

    select * into ##TEMPTABLE FROM @count 

    SET @STMT = 'SELECT * FROM ##TEMPTABLE'
    SET @bodyHTML ='Test ODV'
    SET @mailSubject ='Supervision ODV'

    USE msdb

    EXEC  @RtnCode = sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'Fooo',
      @query_result_separator=@Separateur,
      @recipients = 'foooo@foo.com', 
      @subject = @mailSubject,
      @query = @STMT,      
      @Attach_Query_result_as_file = 0

    IF @RtnCode <> 0
      RAISERROR('Error.', 16, 1)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on msdn of [sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

@query parameter expects a nvarchar(max) type not a Table.

replace

```
@query = @res
```

with

```
@query = 'SELECT
      SiteCode
      ,MAX(DateODV) AS DateLastODV
  FROM Configuration.ODVCompteur
  where year(DateODV) = 2015
  group by SiteCode
  order by DateLastODV desc'
```

EDIT:

While running this as a Job make sure the credentials being used by the SQL Agent service account have enough privileges to execute such query.

For testing purposes try executing as another login with
[execute as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx)

Comment: Of course I already tried this but got an error like that : `Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters [SQLSTATE 42000] (erreur 22050).` The query works perfectly in the other case

Comment: you should check what credentials are being supplied when running the Job. You should look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112849/sp-send-dbmail-executed-from-job-fails-with-query-result-attached-as-file